# How can ServiceStack.OrmLite ignore a property by attribute

Tags: orm, servicestack

```
public class User
{
   public long Id {get;set;}

   [References(typeof(City))]
   public long CityId {get;set;}

   [????]
   public City {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to use ServiceStack.OrmLite. I'm using both ReferenceKey(CityId) and Reference (City). ReferenceKey is for Db creation, Reference is for using object in my code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IgnoreAttribute .. Tested, it works.

Comment: [Ignore] is to ignore from OrmLite, [IgnoreDataMember] is to ignore from Serializer

Answer (score 2):

Try the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.

This attribute will tell the ServiceStack libraries to ignore this property.